# Bash: control a prompt program

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, fsck, prompt

I've searched all over Google and the StackExchange sites, but all of the answers may work for the programs they used, but not for [this](https://github.com/octacian/timecalc/releases/download/v1.0.0/timecalc-linux) ([timecalc](https://github.com/octacian/timecalc/releases/download/v1.0.0/timecalc-linux)).

This program is similar of fsck, having a ">>>+" prompt when opened and, apparently, not supporting receiving programmatic usage/commands unless through a Bash trick.

How to send commands to timecalc as if using its prompt but from an external bash script? [OPTIONAL] Bonus: a solution that works also at fsck and most of other prompt/interaction-only programs.

`./timecalc` sample command to test: `15:00 - 5:00` (should return "10:00" to the bash script)

Comment: You could consider using [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/) (available from the Ubuntu `universe` repository) instead ex. `dateutils.ddiff -f %0H:%0M 5:00 15:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
$ echo 15:00 - 5:00 | timecalc-linux | head -n1 | sed 's,^>>> ,,'
10:00
```

Comment: It works! Many thanks. Would this solution also work for fsck by adapting the ">>" in sed?

Comment: I think it would but you should ask a separate question, maybe you just need `yes`